# How to set sqlite TEMP_STORE to 3 with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using python and sqlite3 and would like to use the memory for temp files. According to the docs, https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html, SQLITE_TEMP_STORE=3 means "Always use memory". I can check the current value with:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
check_db = conn.execute( """ select * from pragma_compile_options where compile_options like 'TEMP_STORE=%' """).fetchall() 

print("check_db:", check_db)
```

When I attempt to update:

```
sq_update = """ update pragma_compile_options set compile_options = 'TEMP_STORE=3' where compile_options like 'TEMP_STORE=1' """ 
conn.execute(sq_update) conn.commit()
```

The following error is returned.
INTERNALERROR> sqlite3.OperationalError: table pragma_compile_options may not be modified

My goal is to set tell sqlite to use the memory for temp files.

Comment: I understand "compiling" but I am not clear how it applies to sqlite3 since I have never compiled sqlite3 before.

Comment: Well, an RDBMS cannot (re)compile itself via an SQL statement. This PRAGMA provides metadata info on settings used during SQLite compilation.

Comment: Note, the compile option can be set to 3, but the largest value of this pragma is 2. See the reference in the answer. As I indicated, you need to use `conn.execute("PRAGMA temp_store = 2;")`, NOT `conn.execute("PRAGMA temp_store = 3;")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to examine the content of `pragma_compile_options` output to see the value of `TEMP_STORE`. You can only change the run-time setting if `TEMP_STORE` was explicitly set to non-zero value. In that case, use `PRAGMA temp_store = 2` to achieve your goal. See https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_temp_store.

Comment: Thank you for the response, are `PRAGMA` and `SQLITE_TEMP_STORE` environment variables?

Comment: No, SQLITE_TEMP_STORE is a compile option (actually, it controls compilation via a C preprocessor directive. Most of SQLite compilation options do the same. You can  fetch all rows from `pragma_compile_options` and see if `SQLITE_TEMP_STORE` is there.

PRAGMA is a special SQLite statement. See the link above at the very top for further details. So you need to do `conn.execute("PRAGMA temp_store = 2;")`.

Comment: Well, it look like you already checked the value of `TEMP_STORE` and it is set to 1. Note, I made a mistake, you do not need "SQLITE_" prefix in this context.